# Find out when keyboard layout is changed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am writing an onscreen keyboard and would like to redraw my layout as soon as keyboard layout is changed.

Currently I call:

```
GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL));
```

on every key press to find out if the layout has changed. It does not work if user changes the layout by mouse, until key is pressed.

I would like to know if there is any way to get notified 
when the keyboard layout of the current foreground window is changed,
so I can redraw my layout as soon as the change happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***There is a way ...***

First you need to register your application to capture foreground window changes:
Use [`SetWinEventHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) with `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` *(and `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT` as it's .NET)* for that.

If that happens: Use your `GetKeyboardLayout` solution for getting the current layout of that window.

Then use a local [***Windows Hook***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms644990.aspx) *(you're probably using it low-level-globally for key captures)* with [`WH_CALLWNDPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms644975.aspx) and the thread of the new foreground window.
Listen to [**`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632629.aspx) messages to that window to receive changes to the layout.
*(You may want to unhook/rehook after another foreground change)*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keyboard layout is stored here:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload

When I changed keyboard languages, the order of settings there changed.

So you could possibly monitor the registry entry.  Here's one way:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx

Comment: Order of values in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload changes only when you change default keyboard layout or add new keyboard layout