# C# Winforms - Get and update current keyboard language in background

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, input, thread-synchronization

I want to make a function that gets the current keyboard language of the user, while it is running in the background (form is hidden). I've tried to use `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name` but for some reason it doesn't work properly in threads - it doesn't update after the user is switching between languages. I tried a lot of different approaches such as using timers, but everything that use any form of threads just don't work.

I also noticed a strange behavior - when I create a MessageBox after getting the current language, it magically updates.

Can someone help or explain to me what should I do?

(English isn't my native language so I'm sorry if this post isn't very clear).

Comment: What kind of Thread are you referring to? This setting is Thread-specific and requires a STA Thread -- See the notes about [GetKeyboardLayout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout). Also the notes about [SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged)

Comment: Maybe these topics could help: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289492/find-out-when-keyboard-layout-is-changed), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573039/windows-event-for-change-in-layout-name-for-the-current-input-language)(WPF) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617159/hook-detect-windows-language-change-even-when-app-not-focused)(WPF).

Comment: Thank very much, your solutions work well :)